# Changing representations: Upper triangular matrix and compact vector (Octave / Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, octave, triangular

Given a matrix **A**, that has zeros on its diagonal and its lower triangular part:

```
A = triu(rand(5,5), 1) % example

A =
0.00000   0.47474   0.55853   0.30159   0.97474
0.00000   0.00000   0.03315   0.74577   0.20878
0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.54966   0.76818
0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.82598
0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

I want to convert **A** into a compact vector **v** that skips all the zero elements:

```
v = [0.47474 0.55853 0.30159 0.97474 0.03315
     0.74577 0.20878 0.54966 0.76818 0.82598]
```

Later I want to convert from the vector back to the matrix.

***Question: What is an elegant way to convert between these two representations?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with an upper triangular matrix of ones

```
B = triu(ones(5,5), 1)
```

And Then **v** can be defined as:

```
v = A(B==1)
```

Converting back from **v** to **A**

```
A = B
A(B==1) = v
```

Comment: Neat ! and another few characters

Answer (score 1):

Because Matlab stores arrays in column-major order I couldn't do this in one statement, well not yet, but here's a two statement solution:

```
B = A';

v = B(B~=0)'
```

@dustincarr's answer renders further work by me redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = triu(rand(5,5), 1);
v = reshape(nonzeros(A'), [5 2])';
```